# Access denied Tortoise SVN 64 bits

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was using tortoise svn 32 bits in XP without problems.

Now, I installed Windows Vista 64 bits and Tortoise SVN 64 bits.

When I try to do an `SVN Update`, I got the error

> Can´t open file C:....svn\lock: Access denied.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you've reinstalled Windows, it may be that the access rights for your folder(s) are configured wrong, so that an unknown SID is the owner or has read/write permission but not your user account.

Maybe check the file permissions of your local SVN files and make sure that your current user/your TortoiseSVN process has the neccessary access rights to change these files.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason my user with administrative rights did not have full control permission to the project folder.

Answer (score 7):

In my case problematic file was locked by Visual Studio, so I could not either update or clean working copy. Closing VS solved the issue. You can use [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) or similar to see if anything is locking your files.

Comment: Had similar issue with Adobe Acrobat locking a file

Comment: Same problem with Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Have similar issue with Java Decompiler

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this post to download an older build of tortoise svn 64-bit to see if you are having similar problem
http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2011-09/0244.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too upgrading from 1.8.8 to 1.9.2.
It was because TSVNCache.exe was running.

Thanks to Dan Dar3's blog:
http://dandar3.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/tortoisesvn-installation-insufficient.html